# lprコマンドで更新日時による印刷指定

Tags: lpr

mac(bash)でlprコマンドで印刷する場合、特にファイル名などを指定せずに、最新の更新ファイルのみ印刷とか、最新ファイルから2枚まで印刷などはできますでしょうか。

ファイル名を指定するのが面倒なので、例えば
ls -lsとすると最新ファイルからソートされますが、上から３枚までを印刷するというようなことです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下でいかがでしょうか。

```
lpr $(ls -1t | head -3)
```

`ls -1t` の出力を上から3行取り出し、lpr のコマンドライン引数として渡しています。